# PHP: str_word_count(åäöåäöåäöåäö) returns the integer value of 12

Tags: php, html, count, cpu-word

I am using special symbols such as å ä ö on my website which measures the lengths of different texts. Thing is, I have noticed that PHP counts the symbols "å" "ä" "ö" as 1 word each. So åäö counts as 3 words, and åäöåäöåäöåäöåäö counts as 15 words. Well this is clearly not correct and I cannot find an answer to this problem anywhere. I'd be thankful for a useful answer, thank you!

Comment: [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/str_word_count) is only intended for ASCII strings. Umlauts require Latin-1 or UTF-8 support.

Comment: `For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters`.... what have you set your locale as?

Comment: Mark Baker, I don't know, how do I check that?

Comment: Mario, ok.. So is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: you could probably do some conversion with preg_replace before measuring to get around this

Comment: Joe T. I tried this method and it eventually worked, It turned out it doesn's work if you use htmlentities() before that. Why did you remove your answer?

Answer (score 2):

If there's a limited set of word characters that you need to take into account, just supply those into `str_word_count` with its third param (`charlist`):

```
$charlist = 'åäö';
echo str_word_count('åäöåäöåäöåäöåäö', 0, $charlist); // 1
```

Alternatively, you can write your own Unicode-ready `str_word_count` function. One possible approach is splitting the source string by non-word symbols, then counting the resulting array:

```
function mb_str_word_count($str) {
  return preg_match_all('#[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N}\'-]*#u', $str);
}
```

Basically, this function counts all the substrings in the target string that start with either Letter or Number character, followed by any number (incl. zero) of Letters, Numbers, hyphens and single quote symbols (matching the description given in `str_word_count()` docs).

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer but it only works in that specific case, when I try to count the words in a normal text it returns to normal. Here is a example of a sentence: "Den första november i år, för 23 dagar sedan tackade hon alla som gett henne support och alla hennes vänner."

Comment: `$count = preg_match_all('~\w+~u', $str)` might be simpler.

Comment: It will also take `_` into account.

Comment: Hmm, sorry but could you specify that? I don't know much about Regex :/

Comment: @georg On the second thought, it's indeed easier to cover all the special cases with `preg_match_all`.

Comment: preg_match_all('~\w+~u', $str) What does this do?

Comment: @Alien13 Matches all the substrings in `$str` that contain either Letter or Number characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
```

before your call to str_word_count
or roll on your own with

```
substr_count(trim($str), ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me... hope its usefull.

USING str_word_count you need to use utf8_decode(utf8_encode)..

```
function cortar($str)
{
    if (20>$count=str_word_count($str)) {
        return $str;
    }
    else
    {
        $array = str_word_count($str,1,'.,-0123456789()+=?¿!"<>*ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ@|/%$#¡');
        $s='';
        $c=0;
        foreach ($array as $e) {
            if (20>$c) {
                if (19>$c) {
                $s.=$e.' ';
                }
                else
                {
                $s.=$e;
                }               
            }
            $c+=1;
        }
        return utf8_decode(utf8_encode($s));
    }
}
```

function returs 20 words

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string without linebreaks, and words **are separated by a whitespace**, a simple workaround would be to `trim()` the string and then count the whitespaces.

```
$string = "Wörk has to be done.";

// 1 space is 2 words, 2 spaces are 3 words etc.
if(substr_count(trim($string), ' ') > 2)
{
   // more than 3 words
   // ...
}
```